# Display a message when user clicks outside of the the minDate/maxDate bounds in a JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using the JQuery datepicker and I have the minDate and maxDate options set correctly so that the dates outside of that span are disabled and grayed out.

No problem.

Now, I want to capture the **event** when a user does try and **select** one of these **disabled dates**.   What event do I need to capture so that I can pop up some exclamatory text?

I've tried onSelect and it doesn't seem to work.  (It would make sense that it's disabled.)

(The business reason, just in case you're wondering why I want to mess with the elegance/obviousness of the grayed-out dates,  is so that I can tell them why these particular dates are out of bounds, and what alternate action to take on the site.)

Any tips?  Or do I have to go in and fuss with the library?

Comment: Not that the user is going to read it anyways, but place a label with that information above the datePicker object

Comment: That would imply a level of subtlety that we've long since abandoned :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just listen for the `click` event on invalid date elements, they have a class of
`ui-datepicker-unselectable`, so you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-unselectable").live('click', function() {
  alert("Invalid date!");
});
```

​
[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qU7Q5/)

Comment: Ah yeah, I'd forgotten that they have their own CSS class.  Thanks.   +1 for JSfiddle!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.ui-datepicker-unselectable').live('click', function() {
        alert("stop! hammer time");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could award points based on alert msg style alone.  Thx.